# Convert IFileStore to IPath in Eclipse RCP

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp

Given an [`IFileStore`](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/core/filesystem/IFileStore.html) and knowledge that it represents a file in the local file system, how can it be converted to the [`IPath`](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/core/runtime/IPath.html)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would go with this:

```
File file = iFileStore().toLocalFile(0, null);
IPath path = Path.fromOSString(file.getCanonicalPath());
```

The other answer would probably work, but the answer here is likely safer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String path = iFileStore.getParent().getName();
...
IPath iPath = Path.fromPortableString(path);
```

You probably have to do some string manipulation on the path string where I have the ellipses.

Since you have the test bed, you can more easily determine what code goes in the ellipses.  Feel free to update this answer with what you find.